# Why is my total price being printed as 0.0 when it should be 11

Tags: java

I am a new java programmer. I am writing a program about restaurant menu but my price is not getting calculated correctly. It gives me 0.0 every time, when it should be 11.0

```
public class Main {

    public static double priceBreadrollType;
    public static double priceMeat;
    public static double totalPrice;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setTotalPrice();
    }

    public static void priceBread (){
        priceBreadrollType = 1;
    }

    public static void priceMeat(){
        priceMeat = 10;
    }

    public static void setTotalPrice(){
        totalPrice = priceBreadrollType + priceMeat;
        System.out.println("The total prize " + totalPrice);
    }



}
```

Comment: static blocks are intialized first ,not static methods.If you want answer to be 11 then use this code
  static {priceBreadrollType = 1;
 priceMeat = 10;
}

Comment: When you step through the code in your debugger, you should be able to answer this for yourself almost immediately.

Answer (score 8):

You never call the `priceBread ()` and `priceMeat()` methods that set the corresponding static variables to `1` and `10`, so they remain `0.0` by default.

Try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    priceBread();
    priceMeat();
    setTotalPrice();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The real issue here is that you are mixing up fields and methods.

You should either use fields only, or just methods to get/update values.

```
priceBreadrollType + priceMeat;
```

Simply adds to fields which are 0 when adding.

Answer (score 0):

There are some different between static block and static method.

```
public class Main {

    public static double priceBreadrollType;
    public static double priceMeat;
    public static double totalPrice;
    static {
        /* priceBreadrollType = 1;
        priceMeat = 10; */
        /* calling the static method in static block or initializing the price are same;  */
        priceBread();
        priceMeat();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setTotalPrice();
    }
    public static void priceBread (){
        priceBreadrollType = 1;
    }
    public static void priceMeat(){
        priceMeat = 10;
    }
    public static void setTotalPrice(){
        totalPrice = priceBreadrollType + priceMeat;
        System.out.println("The total prize " + totalPrice);
    }
}
```